# Performance bottleneck in MySql: number of rows or size of file?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I am building an application using a MySQL database.
I have only one table that is of the form:

```
     Key    | Metadata  | Data
------------+-----------+-----------
  Some GUID | Some info | large data
```

The metadata is a bunch of small columns like DateTime, VarChar(8) and so on.
The data column is a longtext column, that typically contains 250kb of text (but can contain up to several megabytes of text).
I only do lookups using the key (never scanning metadata or data) and the keys are not ordered. I do very few deletes.

Is this table going to scale well? ie. will it be able to handle more than 100000 rows easily?

I know that 100000 rows is a small number for a table, but the table file may take up 25gb, so that's kind of big.

My intuition is that it should work well, since the index will allow MySQL to quickly reach the row it needs to return / edit, but I'm not sure about the size of the table.

This is not an open-ended question: I am looking for an answer that says: it will be fine or it will not be fine, with an explanation of why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about I/O.  And you have multiple problems conspiring against you.

- How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  (I assume the table is InnoDB?)
- GUIDs are terrible because of their randomness.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid
- 250KB of text will be stored "off-record", necessitating at least one extra disk hit to grab it.
- Consider compressing the `LONGTEXT` column.  If it is English text, code, or XML, it will compress about 3:1.  Do the compression/decompression in the client.  Then use `LONGBLOB` instead of `LONGTEXT`.  Smaller -> more cacheable -> less I/O -> faster.

Rolling things together, I see this:

- A "small" ~0.1GB table indexed by a GUID.  This is likely to be cacheable in RAM, even if you have a tiny server.  So, no problem.  And my link about GUIDs is not that relevant, except that it helps explain some things.
- So, once things are warmed up (the 0.1GB is mostly loaded), the main time taken is to fetch the `LONGTEXT` from disk -- it is very unlikely to be cached.
- The `LONGTEXT` will be elsewhere, but you will be fetching them one at a time.
- At 250KB, it will be many disk hits.
- If it is compressed (in the client), then the I/O is 1/3 as much.  That is, Compression is the main fix for performance.  But you will get only 3x speedup.

What will you do with the document?  If you are serving web pages, consider storing them as files, then letting a click go directly to the fs.  That's often the advice for images.